# How to get this type of presentation of question here on forum

Tags: style

I am struggling with the presentation of my questions on to how post here on this forum
I do see here a example question
[Evaluation of this definite integral](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/100013/evaluation-of-this-definite-integral)

- How to get a picture for instance for a integral ( as seen in the example question), other then copy and paste ?

Note: with Maple for example it is possible to copy a picture from a expression in a worksheet
Seems to be not possible in MMA for some reason ?

$ \int_a^b f(x) dx$  : exercise 1

$\int_ 0^1\frac {1} {x^3 + 1}\, dx$  exercise 2

```
Integrate[Exp[-((x[i] - μ[i])^2/(4 s^2)) - (I k (y[i] - x[i])^2)/(2 R)]
          ((y[i] - x[i])/(R^2 + (y[i] - x[i])^2)), {x[i], -∞, ∞}]
```

exercise 3 via code sample in StandardForm

> $\int _{-\infty }^{\infty }\frac{(y(i)-x(i)) \exp
> \left(-\frac{(x(i)-\mu (i))^2}{4 s^2}-\frac{i k
> (y(i)-x(i))^2}{2 R}\right)}{(y(i)-x(i))^2+R^2}dx(i)$

```
TeXForm[Inactive[Integrate][
Exp[-((x[i] - \[Mu][i])^2/(4*s^2)) - (I*k*(y[i] - x[i])^2)/
(2*R)]*((y[i] - x[i])/(R^2 + (y[i] - x[i])^2)), 
{x[i], -Infinity, Infinity}]]
```

---

Comment: It's not exactly a graphics "picture".  It is written in a typesetting language called [LaTeX](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/editing-help#latex).  To see how it works, [edit your question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/posts/263512/edit) and paste in " \int_a^b f(x) dx " at the bottom of your question, but use dollar signs ($) instead of quotes

Comment: Thanks, how do i get then this expression from where? " \int_a^b f(x) dx"
Ah, yes fro MMA : copy as Latex

Comment: Also i do see from this example from a forummember using : StandardForm as input  , while i got the advice to use Raw InputForm ?

Comment: To generate the LaTeX for your 3rd example, evaluate `Inactive[Integrate][ ... ] //TeXForm` in MMA.  You must use `Inactive` to prevent MMA from evaluating the integral.  Check the [documentation for `TeXForm`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TeXForm.html) and search this forum for examples of how to use `TeXForm`.

Comment: Thanks, i will look at it TexForm..

Another problem pops up : 
Your post appears to contain code that is not properly formatted as code. Please indent all code by 4 spaces using the code toolbar button or the CTRL+K keyboard shortcut. For more editing help, click the [?] toolbar icon.

Comment: Latex code into the forum code editor gives a error of course